# Does mongodb have symbolic links?

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB has some dictionaries in it:

```
{
    _id: "a",
    "content": "hello, you!",
},

{
    _id: "b",
    "content": "hello, me!",
}
```

I want to create a third dictionary that is merely a symbolic link to the first dictionary:

```
{
    _id: "c",
    "link_id": "a",
}
```

So dictionary "c" will be nothing more than an alias for dictionary "a".

Does MongoDB support this?  If not, is there a best-practice workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [manual references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references) are indeed the first course of action, and are best in most cases.

If you have special needs, then the built-in Mongo [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) may be your solution, and zangw discussed in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) could meet your requirement

> DBRefs are a convention for representing a document, rather than a specific reference type. They include the name of the collection, and in some cases the database name, in addition to the value from the `_id` field.
>
> DBRefs have the following fields:
>
> `$ref`
>   The $ref field holds the name of the collection where the referenced document resides.
>
> `$id`
>   The $id field contains the value of the _id field in the referenced document.
>
> `$db`
>   Optional.

DBRef documents resemble the following document:

```
 { "$ref" : <value>, "$id" : <value>, "$db" : <value> }
```

Consider a document from a collection that stored a DBRef in a creator field:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5126bbf64aed4daf9e2ab771"),
  // .. application fields
  "creator" : {
                  "$ref" : "creators",
                  "$id" : ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772"),
                  "$db" : "users"
               }
}
```

Comment: This is cool, although Mongo suggests using [manual references](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references) in most cases.  It seems that if everything is in the same collection, there is no added value to using DBRefs.